# Openweathermap API How to make "q" dynamic and coincide with the input of search bar

Tags: javascript, json, rest, weather-api, openweathermap

Hi guys I am new to JSON so I want to create a 'city' search bar so that the user can retrieve the weather of that particular city using the openweathermap API.

This is how you should request it, but I want to make the 'q' in such a way that when a city is correctly typed in the search bar that it automatically retrieves the data of that city. 
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,ca&units=metric&APPID=95d38c513c13444b6290e62403391b4e"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here,its mine: by city search :

```
public final static String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
public final static String yo = "&appid(your id)";
public static final String unit_metric = "&units=metric";
```

and

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(URL + input + yo + unit_metric);
```

where you will be taking input from editext or other
eg: `editext1.getText().toString().trim()`

and `String input=` store here